# Rust different return types with same base structure

Tags: rust

I want to return a different IMAP connection depending on the `secure` variable, but [`imap::client::Client`](http://mattnenterprise.github.io/rust-imap/imap/client/struct.Client.html) returns a different type if we use SSL or not. All of the functions in `Client` are implemented by `impl<T: Read + Write> Client<T>`.

Is there a better and way more efficient solution possible?

```
use error::*;
use imap::client::Client;
use openssl::ssl::{SslConnectorBuilder, SslMethod, SslStream};
use std::net::TcpStream;

pub enum ConnectionResult {
    Normal(Client<TcpStream>),
    Secure(Client<SslStream<TcpStream>>),
}

/// Mail account
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Account {
    pub username: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub domain: String,
    pub port: u16,
    pub secure: bool,
}

impl Account {
    pub fn connect(&self) -> Result<ConnectionResult> {
        if self.secure {
            let ssl_connector = SslConnectorBuilder::new(SslMethod::tls())
                .chain_err(|| "fail with ssl")?
                .build();
            let mut imap_socket = Client::secure_connect(
                (self.domain.as_str(), self.port),
                &self.domain,
                ssl_connector,
            );
            imap_socket
                .login(&self.username, &self.password)
                .chain_err(|| "fail when login")?;
            Ok(ConnectionResult::Secure(imap_socket))
        } else {
            let mut imap_socket = Client::connect((self.domain.as_str(), self.port))?;
            imap_socket
                .login(&self.username, &self.password)
                .chain_err(|| "fail when login")?;
            Ok(ConnectionResult::Normal(imap_socket))
        }
}
```

I just want to return a `Client` struct, not a enum that holds different `Client`s:

```
pub fn connect<T: Read + Write>(&self) -> Result<Client<T>> {
    // But this won't work
}
```

Comment: I just want to return a Client struct, not an enum with different Client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach does not seem bad. My suggest is to use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern): encapsulate your `enum` in a `struct` and do the thing you want in each method with a `match`:

```
enum ConnectionResult { // not pub because intern implementation
    Normal(Client<TcpStream>),
    Secure(Client<SslStream<TcpStream>>),
}

pub struct MyClient {
    connection_result: ConnectionResult,
    // other fields
}

impl MyClient {
    pub fn do_something(&self) {
        match connection_result {
            Normal(client) => // do something with normal client
            Secure(client) => // do something with secure client
        }
    }
}
```

From the user point of view, there is no difference between the two clients.

If you do not want this solution, you can use the nightly `-> impl` feature:

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]

trait MyClient {
    // the methods you need
}

struct NormalClient {
    client: Client<TcpStream>,
    /*etc.*/
}
struct SecureClient {
    client: Client<SslStream<TcpStream>>,
    /*etc.*/
}

impl MyClient for NormalClient { /*etc.*/ }
impl MyClient for SecureClient { /*etc.*/ }

fn get_client() -> impl MyClient { /*etc.*/ }
```